# How to capture XMLHTTP requests in a Webbrowser Control?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, xmlhttprequest

`BeforeNavigate2` event or any other similar event don't catch XMLHTTP requests in a WebBrowser Control. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

This is a .NET project.

**Edit:**

[I've found this C++ application](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.mshtml_hosting/msg/76bf4910a289d4b3) which apparently can be used to solve this problem, but [porting it to managed code doesn't look possible](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/InetSDK/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser_ctl/2006-11/msg00046.html). Maybe I should change the C++ to a COM object and call it from .NET -which won't be easy since it doesn't even compile in VS 2008 due ATL changes I suppose-.

Answer (score 0):

As a 'hack' which would probably equate to jumping through more hoops than necessary you could and may not even help you accomplish what you are looking for.

1)set your browser control to use a proxy uri on the local pc.
2)set up you app to listen for requests on the uri  you specified in step 1 and manipulate what you need to here.